# How to clear all elements in a vector except for the last one in a vector in c++

Tags: c++

As the title says, I have a vector that has 11 integer elements ranging from 1 - 11. I am trying to use the .erase() function to clear all elements in my vector except for the last one. I am having trouble using iterators to do it as they clear out all elements except the first one. I tried a lot of solutions from the internet such as using .rbegin() and .rend() but they just gave me an error.

Here is my code below:-

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<int> epos = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
vector<int>::iterator it1, it2;

int main() {

    it1 = epos.begin();
    it2 = epos.end();

    epos.erase(it1, it2);
    for (int i=0; i<=epos.size(); i++) {
        cout << epos[i] << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am still a beginner in c++ and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there, use this syntax :

```
 // make sure we end up with a vector with one element in it.
 // empty lists will stay empty
 if(epos.size()>1) 
 {
     epos.erase(epos.begin(), epos.end() - 1);
 }
```

And did you know that you can also iterate over containers like this?

```
for (auto v : epos)
{
    cout << v << ' ';
}
```

It's called a range based for loop, and prevents you from making mistakes with indices